# Time complexity :Using big o notation

Tags: java, big-o

I'm a newbie to java development and time complexities and I'm trying to calculate the overall time complexity of this piece of code

```
  void merge (char s[], char t[], char result[]){
  int i, j, k;                          //line 1
  for (i = j = k = 0; (s[i] != ’\0’) && t[j] != ’\0’); k++){  //line2                                            // line 3
      if (s[i] <= t[j])             // line 4
       result[k] = s[i++];          // line 5
      else                          // line 6
       result[k] = t[j++];          // line 7
   }                                // line 8
   for (; s[i] != ’\0’; i++ ) {     // line 9                               
     result[k] = s[i];              // line 11
   }                                // line 12
   for (; t[j] != ’\0’; j++ ){       //line 13                              
    result[k] = t[j];               // line 15
   }                                // line 16
     result[k] = 0;                 // line 17
 }
```

Comment: This is not a question but an implicit work assignment.

Comment: I'm pleased for you.  Did you have a question?  Maybe one that does not run along the lines of "please do my homework for me"?

Answer (score 1):

I think I am correct in saying that as there are no nested loops and no early termination criteria then the above algorithm is O(n)

Comment: `O(n)` is useless without telling what `n` is.